# How to pass in functions as arguments in Rcpp / C++?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm trying to write a function which can take in functions as its arguments in Rcpp. I have written an example function in R that shows the kind of functionality that I'm aiming for:

```
simulate_and_evaluate <- function(simulate, evaluate) {
  y <- simulate(1)
  eval <- evaluate(y)
  return(eval)
}

simulate_fun <- function(n) rnorm(n, 0, 1)
evaluate_fun <- function(x) dnorm(x, 0, 1)

simulate_and_evaluate(simulate = simulate_fun,
                      evaluate = evaluate_fun)
```

In this function `simulate_and_evaluate`, this takes in two arguments which are both functions, one that simulates a number and one that evaluates a function with this simualted number. So as an example, we can simulate a value from a standard normal and evaluate the density of a standard normal at that point. Does anyone know if there's a way to do this in Rcpp?

Comment: Is there a reason you are tying to use Rcpp here? Is it to speed up code? Because if you are trying to call a standard R function in c++ land you probably wont get much of a boost. Rcpp works create if you are running efficient c++ code. But that doesn't seem to be what you are trying to do here.

Comment: There's a guide on doing this [here](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/230_R_function.html)

Comment: Also see package RcppDE with a worked example of passing _compiled_ user-supplied functions around to an optimizer.

Comment: @MrFlick In the actual functions that I wish to implement, I take in these functions to simulate and evaluate densities, but also perform other operations with these results. I hoped that by being able to turn some of the R code that did this into Rcpp code, this would give me some improved performance. I understand that by just calling the basic R functions in C++ wouldn't improve performance, but hoped the other things the function would do with the results of these functions would increase efficiency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rcpp aims for *seamless* interfacing of R and C++ objects. As functions are first class R objects represented internally as a type a `SEXP` can take, we can *of course* also ship them with Rcpp.  There are numerous examples.

So here we simply *rewrite* your function as a C++ function:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("double simAndEval(Function sim, Function eval) {
  double y = as<double>(sim(1));
  double ev = as<double>(eval(y));
  return(ev);
}")
```

And we can then set the RNG to the same value, run your R function and this C++ function *and get the same value*.  Which is awesome.

```
R> set.seed(123)
R> simulate_and_evaluate(simulate = simulate_fun,
+ evaluate = evaluate_fun)
[1] 0.341
R> set.seed(123) # reset RNG
R> simAndEval(simulate_fun, evaluate_fun)
[1] 0.341
R>
```

But as @MrFlick warned you, this will *not run any faster* because we added *no compiled execution of the actual functions* we are merely calling them from C++ rathern than R.

The topic has been discussed before. Please search StackOverflow, maybe with a string `[rcpp] Function` to get some meaningful hits.